# How to deal with WinAPI macros overriding some function names?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, macros

`<windows.h>` defines macroses for Ansi and Unicode versions of WinAPI.
I have a function named `SendMessage` in my class library. It works fine until `<windows.h>` is included before including my library. In this case `SendMessage` is overrided by the macros and the function  name becomes `SendMessageA` or `SendMessageW`.

Is it possible to somehow deal with it without changing the name of the function in order to save compatibility with older versions of the library?

Comment: I'm pretty sure either Herb Sutter or Raymond Chen wrote an article about this exact problem, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: The true issue here is that you have opted to use symbols that clients of your library potentially cannot name.

Comment: that is why modern C libraries have prefixes for their functions, types and macros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is that WinAPI's function definitions are at the C-preprocessor level, and so you have to write some ugly code to try to coexist with them.

If at all possible, you should rename your codebase's functions so that there is no collision with WinAPI.

---

Otherwise, you can write code like `#undef SendMessage` to undefine WinAPI's definition of this function before defining your own function.

If you need to switch between defining your own functions and using WinAPI's function macros, you can also use the `#pragma push_macro` and `#pragma pop_macro` functionality to preserve the macro before the `undef` and restore it afterwards.

Comment: The second paragraph won't help much. The moment a *client* of the library chooses to `#include <Windows.h>` they cannot call into the library anymore.

Comment: I really wish Microsoft would finally get rid of these conflicting `TCHAR` macros for C, or at least disable them when compiling code for C++. Using overloaded inline functions would have been a much safer option.